# How to specify custom hostname in Web Performance and Load Test

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, performance-testing, load-testing

The URLs to load test are bound to a specific hostname that is not publicly resolvable, let's say **private.acme.com**

I can normally perform tests using Chrome Postman and a HOSTS file entry. However, how would this work from the Visual Studio cloud-based load testing? Specifically using a Visual Studio Web Performance and Load Testing Project.

The website is in a very controlled environment, so making changes to it is not an option, e.g. binding *:80 for a short time - is *not* happening.

I have thought of manually spinning up 5 instances of Azure VMs with VS2015 on each, using local HOSTS file entries. But that's 5 agents and a very poor alternative to VSTS.

Comment: Do you refer to that blog and success doing load test?

Answer (score 1):

You can load test apps or sites that are only available to your company, like internal or pre-release apps, staging or preproduction deployments. To learn more, see Load testing applications behind a firewall using Trusted IP (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/03/09/load-testing-applications-behind-firewall-using-trusted-ip/) or you can run a load test locally using Visual Studio (https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/test/performance-testing/run-performance-tests-app-before-release).

Check this article (Q&A): https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/performance-testing/getting-started/getting-started-with-performance-testing#general

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the detailed information of your website environment, but you can check the solutions in following image and then figure out the best solution according to your environment:
[image]

Refer to this link for details: [Testing private/intranet applications using Cloud-based load testing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/08/23/testing-privateintranet-applications-using-cloud-based-load-testing/).

Answer (score 0):

Load tests run on VSTS use Microsoft's cloud computers using Microsoft accounts. The URLs must be visible from those computers and accounts (although the test can provide other credentials in the requests that are sent). If the domain names are not publically resolvable then you should be able to use the IP addresses in the tests. The "parameterise web servers" command in the web test editor will convert all URLs in requests from (eg) `http://private.acme.com/one/two/three` to `http://{{WebServer1}}/one/two/three` (or similar) plus creating the context parameter. You can then alter context parameter's value to the required IP address.

Be aware that the "parameterise web servers" command does not change all uses of the name. Strings such as `http%3A%2F%2Fprivate.acme.com%2F` are often missed, so I recommend checking and editing, if necessary, the XML text in the ".webtest" file to ensure that all uses are changed.

Comment: You are providing commentary that does not answer the question

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi then please edit your question to describe the real problem and to make it answerable. I tried really hard to understand what you were asking and to provide some help. It may be that the real answer to your question is that what you want cannot be done.

Comment: The question is in the title. Need custom domain name resolution to be recognised by VSTS load test.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi What does the phrase "custom domain name resolution" mean? Whilst I have some ideas I do not know what it might mean in connection with VSTS. I have searched for the term here on Stack Overflow and on the sister sites Server Fault and Super User. I have also searched on Google. My searches have been quick, but I have not found any explanation of what the phrase means. Let me request again: please edit your question to fully explain what you are trying to do. As an aside: there are several things that I would like VSTS load tests to provide but they are currently impossible.